# Build fails on private Gitlab build server

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with a gitlab runner that I set up in my local network. When the runner starts a build it fails saying it cannot find the .Net core SDK, however when I log into the server and run the commands by hand the build succeeds.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Tools\Nuget\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
stages:
    - build
    - test

build:
    stage: build
    only:
        - branches
    script:
        - 'cd Project'
        - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
        - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly'

    artifacts:
      paths:
        - bin/

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "dotnet test"
```

This is the output

```
$ cd Project
$ & "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.3.1.50202' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\_edited_\0\_edited_\project\Project\Project\Project.csproj : error : Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\_edited_\0\_edited_\project\Project\Project\Project.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The exact error message would be helpful. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the runner is running as the user that has the SDK or Install the SDK Globally.